# Getting error while trying to save file in grid-fs using mongoose and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, gridfs, gridfs-stream

Trying to get GridFSBucket working for mongoose but no luck even after spending 2 days on it. I was getting a warning related to GridStore so thought of using GridFSBucket as we are using mongoose so referred the [link](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html#-gridstore-) but the same code is not working for me.

Following is the code I tried -

```
var express = require('express');
var gridfsService = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

const conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://user:password@127.0.0.1:27017/dbname');
const gridFsBucket = new mongoose.mongo.GridFSBucket(conn.db);
```

The error I am getting is -

```
 _chunksCollection: db.collection(options.bucketName + '.chunks'),
                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined
    at new GridFSBucket (d:\Projects\myapp\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\gridfs-stream\index.js:50:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (d:\Projects\myapp\services\myapp.service.js:6:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous>
```

I am using following versions - Nodejs-8.11.2 Mongoose- 5.0.0 mongodb - 4.0.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to downgrade mongoose version from latest seeing to suggestions. It worked on mongoose version 4.13.17 ([legacy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose)). Any other solution/suggestion is most welcome.